# How to use mqtt websocket api in python

Tags: python, websocket, mqtt

I am trying to use mqtt protocol in this websocket api address `wss://meri.digitraffic.fi:61619/mqtt` .

It has username and password `userName:digitraffic`

`password:digitrafficPassword`.

plus (ssl needs to be enable) and i need to subscribe the message `vessels/#` from that websocket api address .

I have found some links [MQTT over websocket in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621075/mqtt-over-websocket-in-python).

I have also followed documentation of this one https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/ and it works if i put the exact address given in the documentation but fails when I put my above address with username and password.

How can i use my websocket address in that paho-mqtt. Can this achieve using simple websocket library ? I am new in this stuff and any kind of help would be helpful.

Comment: can you share the codes here ? You can refer to the following example. It looks more straight forward answer for your case http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-websockets/

Comment: I fixed this by using paho-mqtt libs. For someone who has faced same problem like me  needs to use  `on_connect`, `on_message` function from paho-mqtt. Also transport should be websockets. For eg. `myclient = pahoClient.Client(clientId, transport='websockets')`